# Problemas con input dateTime-local

Tags: javascript

Resulta que tengo un input tipo datetime-local en un formulario, quisiera saber si es posible que cuando selecciono la fecha me aparece asi  2021-01-10T21:37 desearía que solo se borre el "T" después de la hora

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="myDate" value="2000-05-05">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: el valor que tiene el input con id "myDate" tiene la siguiente fecha en string? 2021-01-10T21:37, el código no esta claro, pues en el valor tienes "2000-05-05", puedes revisarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Mira lo hice de la siguiente manera: Puedes utilizar el replace para eliminar la T y poner un espacio, espero te funcione!

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<input type="datetime-local" id="myDate"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDate").value.replace('T', " ");
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: El código que proporcionas en la respuesta no esta claro, no se ve la fecha String en el Input tag, ni la operación replace en acción, puedes revisarlo?